# Start-Service and Stop-Service command lets capture console output

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I have a windows service that logs quite a bit to the console when it starts or stops. Unfortunately all of this information is not visible when I try to start or stop it with powershell(Stop-Service, Start-Service). Any idea how I can get access to it?

Edit: I use Console.WriteLine

Output :

[image]

Comment: What API (method) are you calling to log information to the console?

Comment: Please post text content instead of screenshot. You can change service name instead of this yellow mess.

Comment: So to make it less messy I will translate it here. "Warning: Waiting for service SERVICE_NAME to start ...."

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand your service is not sending informations to the console. It's just the Service Control Manager (SCM) that sends messages because the 'startService' function (initialization of your service) is not answering in a given time.

Comment: My service is sending information it just does not appear in the console.

Comment: The message : "Warning: Waiting for service SERVICE_NAME to start" comes from the SCM. It's not sent by your service.

Comment: and that's the problem. I do send messages to the console but they get lost.